# Solving system of linear equations

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, equation-solving

My goal is to solve the system of equation known as Lyapunov equation, that is finding x in the following equation:

```
A*X + X*transpose(A) +Q = 0
```

plus another linear constraint that is `X*v = 0`

where all matrices A, X ,Q are n by n matrices and v is a vector with length n.

How can I find such X in matlab?

Comment: Have you tried to use Google to find a solver? I am confident that you will find many useful sites. If you still have a question please modify the original one according what you have found, tried. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Solving Lyapunov equations in Matlab is very easy. Both the continuous and discrete Lyapunov equation have a built-in function:

- Continuous Lyapunov equation: `lyap` ([see Matlab documentation here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lyap.html))
- Discrete Lyapunov equation: `dlyap` ([see Matlab documentation here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html))

**Extra note**: if the links would not work, or you want a quick way to check the documentation of a Matlab function offline, every built-in Matlab function has a short help page reachable by `help NameOfTheFunction`.
Furthermore the extended help page, as also visible on the web, with examples can also be retrieved offline by typing `doc NameOfTheFunction` in the Matlab terminal.

## Example

Given the following continuous Lyapunov equation:

```
A*X + X*transpose(A) + Q =  0
```

The solution in Matlab for a stable `A` and positive definite `Q` is given as:

```
X = lyap(A,Q)
```

In some cases the equation is slightly different:

```
A*X + X*B + C = 0
```

This equation calls the Sylvester equation and is again solvable with the built-in Lyapunov function of Matlab:

```
X = lyap(A,B,C)
```

The same analogue solution steps exist for the discrete case, where the Lyapunov and Sylvester equation look slightly different:

```
A*X*transpose(A) -X + Q = 0 -> X = dlyap(A,Q)
A*X*B - X + C = 0 -> X = dlyap(A,B,C)
```

Comment: Common Stack Overflow convention is to include boilerplate solution code in answer. External links may expire. While I agree that's not very likely in case of MATLAB official docs, a little piece of code really helps answer to shine.

Comment: @ChristofVermeersch Thanks, I am well aware of that. However, lyap is for the case that matrix A is full rank (i.e. rank of A is n). Since rank of my matrix  A is n-1 lyap doesn't work. However, adding the condition X*v = 0 causes X to have a unique  solution. But I am asking how can I do it?

Comment: I suppose that this is only solvable by using an iterative method, which uses Krylov Subspace iterations. Is there a particular reason why your matrix is not of full rank?